# When refreshing the contents of DataGridView, it's not remembering the DataGridViewCheckBox if clicked - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Basically, when I add a new task to my List and display it, it works fine and this is the code I used to add a new task and display the set of tasks:

Add task code on addTask.cs:

```
    taskStructure.TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure
    {
        taskID = taskIDValueTxt.Text,
        taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
        taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text,
        taskPriority = checkedButton,
        taskDateAndTimeCompletion = finishDateAndTimeDTP.Text,
        taskCompleted = mainPage.testerrr
     });
```

testerrr is just a public static bool that I was trying to use to get
the value selected via the user in the DataGridViewCheckBoxCell for each task, but this did not work using

```
testerrr = Convert.ToBoolean(((tasksViewerDGV.Rows[i].Cells["taskCompleted"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value));
```

Display task code on mainPage.cs

```
    //Change it from null to the List<T> so the DataGridView can update itself with the new and current task values
    taskStructureBindingSource.DataSource = null;
    taskStructureBindingSource.DataSource = taskStructure.TasksArray;
```

Basically if the user marks the task as completed, I want that value to stay to that particular task e.g True. However, when I refresh the DataGridView, the 'ticked' values just get changed back to false (Unticked). Is there anyway that when I click the checkbox for that task to make it stay checked when I refresh?

Kieran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set DataProperty of the DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn to "taskCompleted" to bind values of this column to the taskCompleted property of taskStructure objects.

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't realise it was that easy! Answer marked 